# How to handle an error caused by another module

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to make a web spider and everything is working fine except when I try to get the link I can't really control the input with **try and expect**
and what I noticed is like there are two errors actually happening.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is if anything other than a regular URL is given as an input it shows a message and ask for the input again
**(I don't know how to address the error)**

```
while True:
    try:
        url = input("please enter your site (with no http:// ) : ")
        link = ur.urlopen("http://"+url)
        break
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
```

This code gives

```
Unexpected error: <class 'urllib.error.URLError'>
```

**assuming we enter an invalid url**

and the rest goes like this - I don't know if it's important or not

```
import urllib.request as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

##core 
while True:
    try:
        url = input("please enter your site (with no http:// ) : ")
        link = ur.urlopen("http://"+url)
        break
    except:
        print("please enter a valid url ")
        raise

source=link.read()
scrapy = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
```

Comment: It's also best practice to catch a specific type of exception. You shouldn't have bare except clauses. Instead you should catch `URLError`. [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.URLError)

Answer (score 0):

The raise keyword raises an exception and stops the program.
Try removing it. It will just output your "Unexepected error" with your print and stay in the loop, without stopping the program.

Comment: yes , if i delete raise it works but is there anyway to address this error instead of a blank except

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is that you raise again. If you remove the raise after the print m, it should work the way you want.

Comment: yes , if i delete raise it works but is there anyway to address this error instead of a blank except

Comment: You can just catch this exception with: except urllib.error.URLError:

Comment: oh really sorry truly a rookie mistake that was't working because it didn't recognize urllib

Comment: it gave `undefined variable urllib` and I  thought I couldn't address it like that

Comment: You need to import it like: from urlib.error import URLError and then: except URLError